# How to display next planned check?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table which is called TASK_CHECK and it looks like this:

| type | COMPLETION_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| KDA | 17.12.2021 |
| KDB | 18.12.2021 |

There is another table which is called TASK_SCHEDULE, which looks like this:

| check_id | type | SCHEDULED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | KDA | 19.12.2021 |
| 202 | KDA | 22.12.2021 |
| 203 | KDA | 23.12.2021 |
| 204 | KDB | 21.12.2021 |
| 205 | KDB | 23.12.2021 |

Now I need to display first table but with one more column, I need to  display the first next check_id from second table which happens after completion date. For example:

| type | COMPLETION_DATE | SCHEDULED_DATE | check_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KDA | 17.12.2021 | 19.12.2021 | 201 |
| KDB | 18.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 | 204 |

Comment: Please correct your example and add the expected column

Comment: Your results are identical to your source table.

Comment: It looked like that because of poorly edited question by another person; I rolled it back, now it looks as it should have, @Stu.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option (sample data in lines #1 - 12; you don't need that - query you might be interested in begins at line #14):

```
SQL> with
  2  task_check (type, completion_date) as
  3    (select 'KDA', date '2021-12-17' from dual union all
  4     select 'KDB', date '2021-12-18' from dual
  5    ),
  6  task_schedule (check_id, type, scheduled_date) as
  7    (select 201, 'KDA', date '2021-12-19' from dual union all
  8     select 202, 'KDA', date '2021-12-22' from dual union all
  9     select 203, 'KDA', date '2021-12-23' from dual union all
 10     select 204, 'KDB', date '2021-12-21' from dual union all
 11     select 205, 'KDB', date '2021-12-23' from dual
 12    )
 13  --
 14  select c.type, c.completion_date, s.scheduled_date, s.check_id
 15  from task_check c join task_schedule s on s.type = c.type
 16  where s.scheduled_date = (select min(s1.scheduled_date)
 17                            from task_schedule s1
 18                            where s1.type = s.type
 19                              and s1.scheduled_date > c.completion_date
 20                           );

TYP COMPLETION SCHEDULED_   CHECK_ID
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
KDA 17.12.2021 19.12.2021        201
KDB 18.12.2021 21.12.2021        204

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `CROSS JOIN` a *lateral derived table*:

```
select c.type, c.completion_date, s.scheduled_date, s.check_id
from task_check c
  cross join lateral (select * from task_schedule
                      where type = c.type
                        and scheduled_date > c.completion_date
                      order by scheduled_date
                      fetch first 1 row only) s
```